# How can I see all connection attempts with my GAE server?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-platform

I am running my application on GAE, for ex., http://example.appspot.com.
I think the standard log displays the details related to HTTP/HTTPS connections with my server. What if someone tries to connect with telnet? ftp? or any other way of connection? Or user connects with HTTPS, but with wrong certificate? Where could I see all such attempts?

Comment: Do you run GAE on standard or flexible version? What's your concern there maybe someone try to connecto with telnet or ftp ?

Comment: Someone tries to connect via Telnet ? FTP? Looks like we're missing something here!

Comment: I have 3rd party app, where server details should be defined. But it is unclear how it connects.